# why there is a black background in my QWeb report

Tags: odoo, odoo-10, qweb

I have write a report for my model odoo; but when I print my model, I find that all field has an black background, I don't know why, please give me an advice :

```
report file XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!--<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="view.css"?>-->
<openerp>
    <data>
        <report
            id="action_report_omega"
            model="omega.model"
            string="Report"
            report_type="qweb-pdf"
            file="model_x.report_omega_document"
            name="model_x.report_omega_document"
        />
    </data>
</openerp>
```

and that is my template view :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<openerp>
    <data>
        <template id="report_omega_document">
            <t t-call="report.html_container">
            <t t-call="report.external_layout">
                <div class="page"  style="page-break-after: always;">
                    <div class="header">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-3">
                                <img t-if="res_company.logo" t-att-src="'data:image/png;base64,%s' %res_company.logo"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <hr/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="body">
                        <h2 style="text-align: center; line-height: 2;">ORDER DE MISSION</h2>
                        <div>
                            <table style="border: 1px solid black; width: 100%;">
                                <tr style="padding: 3px;">
                                    <td style="padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px; border: 1px solid black; width: 30%;"><strong>Référence</strong></td>
                                    <td style="padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px; border: 1px solid black;"><p t-field="docs.number"/></td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </div>
[...]
        </template>
    </data>
</openerp>
```

that is the resultI get all time :[image: image here]

and that is the result that I want to see : [image: image here]

I have use this line :

```
<div class="page" style="page-break-after:always; background-color:white !important;">
```

then I get this result : [image: image here]

Comment: it could be the css file, since it calls view.css  look for background-color with alpha, or background-image with a png file.

Comment: I have not add any css file truly I have try to use a css style to change the color but he's not working.

Comment: remove the "page" class and see if that changes the appearance, if it does you do have a css attached.

Comment: I have done as you say, but when print the report give me an empty pdf (no page to show)

Comment: <div class="page"  style="page-break-after: always;background-color:#fff !important;">  try this.

Comment: that work but it still there a black line both side

Comment: update image in question.

Comment: You need to search for the css file that governs this there are several css commands it could be, as well as several classes it could be attached to. Honestly just got lucky with the page class,   try  <template id="report_omega_document" style="background-color:#fff !important;">  might be the template id since it is bigger than the page class.

Comment: did you use external module that overriding odoo's default CSS? Or did you change Odoo's CSS? It's strange on your code is normal, but the result is not normal. I believe it because inheritance issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this worked for me

```
<div class="page" style="page-break-after: always;background-color:#fff !important;">
```